# How to change preset values of a row by selecting from a dropdown list

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am pretty new to Excel but need to make an Excel sheet where I can select the item name so when the selected item changes so do all the values (price) of the column. Once this changes the value when I enter quantity, it would calculate the cost.

I do have this working in 20 different sheets but I want to able to make this work in only one sheet.

Note: Each selected item has about 100 different sub items and that's why I need drop list to override columns with preset values.

How should I approach this?

*Edit not by OP to add image from link provided in comment*

[image: SU602384 example]

Comment: Welcome to SU.  This is a pretty easy task for Excel using either a function (e.g. VLOOKUP) or data validation.  To get a better answer, please add a small sample of your data, and how much you'll need help setting up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming data layout as `D:U etc` in example and `A1` validated according to the List `$G$2:$G$6` then:

in `A2`: `=SUM(B3:B1048576)` {less than 1048576 if an early version of Excel}
in `A3`: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A$1,Table1[#All],ROW()-1,FALSE),"")` and
in `B3`: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,D:E,2,FALSE),"")`

(the latter two copied down as far as necessary) should total subitem costs in`B1` based on the item selection picked from `A1`.

[image: SU602384 first example]

Hopefully items and sub items can be added (with care) without the need to adjust any formula, provided the Table in `A:B` is extended where necessary to ensure at least one blank (but shaded and containing the formula) cell at the bottom of the array in `ColumnA`.

---

*Revised in the light of further information*

To keep the data and calculations on different sheets, name ranges as below:

[image: SU602384 second example]

On a new sheet (add labels as required) in `B4` put:

`=INDEX(prices,MATCH(A4,cabinets,0)+2,MATCH(B3,items,0)+1)`

and add list validation as below:

for `B3`:  Source: `=items`
for `A4`:  Source: `=cabinets`

In `D4` put: `=B4*C4`

Copy Row3:5 down as often as likely to be required and add a total for ColumnD.

[image: SU 602384 third example]

Comment: pnut thank you for taking your time and preparing this i appreciate your help.
is it possible to provide this file? when i try to enter 
in A3: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A$1,Table1[#All],ROW()-1,FALSE),"")
i get an error  cant pass this error.

Comment: ok i got that its working fine thank you this is the table i want this table to work with http://s17.postimg.org/gdwy95x8f/Untitled_1.jpg for example when i select CYOF in B2 it would take those numbers in the column. the formula you have takes the rows. is this possible as well?

Comment: actually this is just pricing sheet there is no formula or anything in it .. what you have created is perfect. I'm just trying to figure out how to insert this formula with this sheet so i enter the quantity it would automatically do all the calculation.... ( I know i ask to much and thank you for all your help.)